# What algorithm to use to determine likelihood of a certain party's actions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scripting, prediction

I am attempting to write an algorithm that will determine the likelihood that a party will bid on an auction given past behavior, available capital, how much they have/ need, etc.  I will be writing a shell that runs the algorithm and returns the result.

What algorithm would be best for solving this?  Also, what scripting language would accomplish this in the best way?

I am very new to creating/ using algorithms so any and all feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question can't just be simply answered by people who are good at writing algorithms. There is a lot of missing information, namely research that shows what effect past actions have on future actions, or what effect varying amounts of money tends to have on a users bidding likelihood.

Comment: Oh I see.  So what would be a proper algorithm to use, once that information is gathered? @leigero

Comment: Again, that will depend entirely on the outcome of that research. If `people who bid a lot in the past never bid again` that's going to be a totally different algorithm than `people who bid in the past bid more frequently in the future.` etc. etc.